# Compute shader - bind all texture's mip maps

Tags: opengl, glsl, directx, shader, compute-shader

is it possible (in OpenGL compute shader) to bind for example 3 mip maps of the same image as image2D structure? 
Right now i have something like this in my compute shader:

```
layout (binding = 0, rgba16) uniform writeonly image2D textureMipMapLevel0;
layout (binding = 1, rgba16) uniform writeonly image2D textureMipMapLevel1;
layout (binding = 2, rgba16) uniform writeonly image2D textureMipMapLevel2;
```

And then:

```
if(z == 0)
{
   imageStore(textureMipMapLevel0, iTextureCoords, vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
}
else if(z == 1)
{
   imageStore(textureMipMapLevel1, iTextureCoords, vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0));
]
else
{
   imageStore(textureMipMapLevel2, iTextureCoords, vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0));
}
```

Is there any function like: getTextureByTextureUnit or something like this to use my z value instead of multiply if and else blocks? Every single time when I chaneg number of mip maps i have to generate completly diffrent shader program...

Comment: That all depends on what `z` is, exactly. And I mean *exactly* what `z` is; where its value comes from and how that value can be used are critically important. Also, what algorithm are you using where this is somehow a good idea? That you're writing data to multiple mipmap levels like this.

Comment: In building quad tree on GPU. Each mip map level represents each level of detail in quad tree. Details here:
https://twvideo01.ubm-us.net/o1/vault/gdc2018/presentations/TerrainRenderingFarCry5.pdf
Z is calculated inside compute shader